# Variable Not Defined After Conditions

Tags: python, variables

This is supposed to be a passcode generator program in Python 3.

```
import string
from random import *

print("Type Yes or No For The Following Questions:")

letters = raw_input("Do you want letters in your passcode?" )
if raw_input == 'Yes': chars1 = string.ascii_letters 
elif raw_input == 'No': chars1  = ""

digits = raw_input("Do you want digits in your passcode?" )
if raw_input == 'Yes':chars2 = string.digits
elif raw_input == 'No': chars2 = ""

symbols = raw_input("Do you want symbols in your passcode?" )
if raw_input == 'Yes': chars3 = string.punctuation 
elif raw_input == 'No': chars3  = ""

requestedlength = input("What passcode length do you want? Type any   number: ")
length = int(requestedlength)

chars = chars1 + chars2 + chars3

passcode = raw_input("Type Enter To Generate Random Passcode: ")
print("".join(choice(chars) for x in range((length))))
```

What am I doing wrong here? The error states that chars1 chars2 and chars3 are not defined. How would I define those variables after they get altered in the conditional statements? I'm pretty new to Python so I apologize if the code is a mess
:(

EDIT: Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: Your variables are defined inside the if so their scope is limited to that if

Comment: What if the user enters neither `Yes` nor `No`? Also `raw_input == 'Yes'` does not make sense. You should check against your variable, e.g. `letters` or `digits`.

Comment: Also, if you're just learning python, start with python3.

Comment: just a warning that choice is not cryptographically random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I get it to work:

```
import string
from random import *

print("Type Yes or No For The Following Questions:")

letters = input("Do you want letters in your passcode?" )
if letters == 'Yes': chars1 = string.ascii_letters 
elif letters == 'No': chars1  = ""

digits = input("Do you want digits in your passcode?" )
if digits == 'Yes':chars2 = string.digits
elif digits == 'No': chars2 = ""

symbols = input("Do you want symbols in your passcode?" )
if symbols == 'Yes': chars3 = string.punctuation 
elif symbols == 'No': chars3  = ""

requestedlength = input("What passcode length do you want? Type any   number: ")
length = int(requestedlength)

chars = chars1 + chars2 + chars3

passcode = input("Type Enter To Generate Random Passcode: ")
print("".join(choice(chars) for x in range((length))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your if statements aren't asking the right thing

You set some variable with the input

```
letters = raw_input("Do you want letters in your passcode?" )
```

and then ask if `raw input` is "Yes", which it never is

```
if raw_input == 'Yes': chars1 = string.ascii_letters
```

So your if statements are always false and the variables (`chars1` etc) never get set, so you get the error

To fix it, simply change your if statement

```
if letters == 'Yes': chars1 = string.ascii_letters
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your "input" typo in your if-statements to "letters" and etc. for other loops:

```
letters = input("Do you want letters in your passcode?")
if letters == 'Yes':
    chars1 = string.ascii_letters
elif letters == 'No':
    chars1 = ""

digits = input("Do you want digits in your passcode?")
if digits == 'Yes':
    chars2 = string.digits
elif digits == 'No':
    chars2 = ""

symbols = input("Do you want symbols in your passcode?")
if symbols == 'Yes':
    chars3 = string.punctuation
elif symbols == 'No':
    chars3 = ""
```

Comment: initialization not required